# Bug with images?

Tags: bug, status-completed, image

I put this in my question to include 2 screenshots:

```
![MP3 Tunes v2 (v1 was much better)][1]
![The largest accurate screenshot I found of v1 >.<][2]
```

And this is what happened:

[image: Screenshot]

The first screenshot shows up, followed by a part of my description, a title attribute, and an end tag...
It looks  like HTML isn't being escaped? Or have I missed something? I don't remember this ever happening before.

Sorry if this is supposed to be like that, but it looks kinda strange to me :p

---

(Yes, I know this is caused by the > I put in the description)

Comment: I found that other characters were also causing this strange behavior (`=` iirc)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115338/angle-brackets-in-image-alt-texts-should-be-auto-encoded

Comment: Thanks for the report; fixed per

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115338/angle-brackets-in-image-alt-texts-should-be-auto-encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report; we have now fixed this per

[Angle brackets in image alt texts should be auto-encoded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115338/angle-brackets-in-image-alt-texts-should-be-auto-encoded)

And the angle brackets are properly encoded >.<